# Enchanting Symbols

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

**What do the symbols mean?**

I know that the lightning represents the charge but there are 2 values, one of which is in parentheses.

The other one is a candle. I don't know what it means.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

about the value you mentioned, 14(85), is related with the charge level. In your picture for example, it means that adding an enchantment of Absorb Magicka 10pts for 1 sec will cost only 14 charges, and you still have 71 charges left (85 - 14 = 71) to add another enchantment! But remember, the higher the charges number, the lower the uses your item will have. Again in the picture, if you only apply as enchantment Absorb Magicka 10pts for 1 you can use your weapon 114 times, but if you add for example Drain Health 10pts for 1 sec, you could end up with 45 uses instead of 114. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

The lightning bolt is the amount of charge that an enchantment consumes every hit. The value inside parentheses depicts the available charge. The candle tells you how many times you can use an enchantment before you need to recharge.

Comment: I am still confused with that 14 ( 85) values